# Calculating MongoDB fill up time

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I made a prototype with Meteor and here are the current stats

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.myCollection.stats()
{
        "ns" : "meteor.myCollection",
        "count" : 73300,
        "size" : 297302888,
        "avgObjSize" : 4055.9739154160984,
        "storageSize" : 305774592,
        "numExtents" : 12,
        "nindexes" : 1,
        "lastExtentSize" : 88891392,
        "paddingFactor" : 1,
        "systemFlags" : 1,
        "userFlags" : 0,
        "totalIndexSize" : 4038944,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 4038944
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
meteor:PRIMARY> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "meteor",
        "collections" : 5,
        "objects" : 73497,
        "avgObjSize" : 4052.9887206280528,
        "dataSize" : 297882512,
        "storageSize" : 305799168,
        "numExtents" : 16,
        "indexes" : 11,
        "indexSize" : 4120704,
        "fileSize" : 1056702464,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Here is my calculation on how fast will 12G Database fill up with **one** Collection (stats above):

```
73,300 Documents – 0.27G of space (fileSize)
271,481 Documents will occupy 1G of space(fleSize)
2,880 Documents is saved per day
68 days to reach 1G of storage space
943 days (2.60 years) to reach 12G storage space
```

There is no plan to delete or modify data, all Documents will be approximately same size and format. My application is real time data display and run queries on stored data.

I don't believe it is precise numbers but how close i am in my calculation to the reality? 
Is there anything else i need to include in my rough estimate?

Comment: Don't forget indexes! Depending on indexes' number, type, and cardinality, the total size can be significant. Unfortunately it's hard to calculate how large they'll be since the structure of the index B-trees depends on insertion order, but some experiments should give you a rough idea of growth.

Comment: @wdberkeley, thanks for a great input, i didn't pay attention to this parameter. So, storageSize parameter doesn't include indexSize, correct?

Comment: Nope. `storageSize` is the total amount of storage that's been allocated in the database for documents. All of the fields are explained in the docs for the [db.stats command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/dbStats/#dbcmd.dbStats).